# Can F# be Used in a Full Web Application

Tags: f#

A while ago - I moved from C# to nodejs / typescript and really enjoyed moving out of OOP into a more functional style ( and LOT fewer bugs ) .

I have recently moved back to .Net due to limitations in reporting frameworks and a few other things ( I still use vue.js for front end stuff ).

I really like F# - but I ran into a few issues with ORM's - and I use a few UI frameworks like Devexpress. Is it worth persevering with F# and can it be used in a fully functional web application - or do parts of it need to be written in C# ( like the DAL ) ?

I'm trying to take a more practical approach rather than a purist "everything-must-be-functional" approach so I don't mind having a few mutables here and there.  Is it really painful to use F# for full applications or are things going to get better?

I realise this is partly opinion based - but those experienced in the language would be able to tell me if it's possible to use F# everywhere or if languages are split.

Thanks

Comment: What issues did you run into with ORM's?

Comment: You also didn't specify the web framework you used.  It's not just DevExpress; that's a Controls Collection.

Comment: Have you seen the SAFE stack? It looks very promising. https://safe-stack.github.io/

Comment: Have a look here: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-mvc-web.aspx/.  Other than fewer braces, there isn't all that much difference between c# and f# in this context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Maybe I'm a bit lazy - but I was looking for a library where I could send the ORM a record and it would update the whole record instead of me having to specify every single field.  The closest I found was Dapper having looked through them all but even had a few issues with that.  I only ended up doing a few things with it as it was a legacy DB  - I am moving to MongoDB .

Comment: @RobertHarvey using ASP.Net Core

Comment: Did you see Dapper.Contrib?

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Thanks - No I hadn't seen that.  It looks good! Thank you

Comment: ORMs are not really a thing in functional programming (remember what O stands for).  If you want to see one way of how to do it, check the domain modeling made functional book  https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/books/   .  However, these days you can pretty much code the same functional designs in C# ( not quite as robust as F#, but still pretty good )

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if F# can be used in a CRUD kind of web app the answer is yes.

You can do (almost) the same things that you do in C# with F# as well. You can use dapper/EF/NHibernate and mimic what you do in C#.

Having that said since you won't be doing functional programming the benefit of using F# diminishes.

If you decide to go with the functional programming style then you should perhaps use an architecture based on CQRS and Event Sourcing instead of using an ORM where FP really shines. But beware, the learning curve is not small.